# Force.com : Rest API Bad Request in Query Like

Tags: apex-code, force.com

I got 'bad request" message on the below Rest API Ajax call, When I tested on Developer console it return data successfully.

```
var _url = auth.get("instance_url") +
    "/services/data/v28.0/query/?q=SELECT Id, Name FROM  Account WHERE Website LIKE '%gmail.com%' ";

$.ajax({
    url: _url,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + auth.getAccessToken()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("accounts:  " + JSON.stringify(data));
        result = data;

    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + +errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to URLEncode the query parameter, spaces are not valid in a query string, e.g.

```
var _url = auth.get("instance_url") + "/services/data/v28.0/query?q=" + encodeURIComponent("select id,name from account");
```